# Cannot find issue with Javascript since console reports no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website uses a Carousel but, it's failing in IE 11. It is working fine in FF and Chrome.

As one expects, the carousel should animate a sequence of slides. In IE, it completes the first, and then stops!

The problem I have is because there is no error message, I can't debug it. This means, I have no idea what code I can share other than providing you a link to the site (which I'm sure is not particularly useful so apologies in advance, but there is nothing else I can show). http://www.lmsites.co.uk/

I'm suspecting the issue is with the bootstrap.js but still, I'm not sure.

What I can tell you is the application.js  (http://www.lmsites.co.uk/Scripts/application.js) file is where the javascript lives for the carousel/slider.

So, my main question is, how do I debug issues like this when there are no reported errors? Is my only option to step through the jquery? Or can some one see what the issue is?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems a valid question about how to debug javascript.

Comment: Step through would indeed be a good option... a bug doesn't always imply an error message, wrong results or faulty behaviour is also a bug, and tracking this is also debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To workout such things you have to look at the source code and understand how the library works, a good start point is at the first call you do to it, there you will start to understand how it works, what functions it calls and things like that. Understanding it you can them follow the execution and sets breakpoints until you get at the issue piece.

OR

What I did was take an overall look to guess how it works and set breakpoints in key places. What called my attention for example was the method cycle

```
cycle: function (e) {
  if (!e) this.paused = false
  this.options.interval
    && !this.paused
    && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))
  return this
}
```

very probable it does the cycling of slides, so I start at it.

But of course, debuging methods are very personal to each one, so what might be easy to me is not easy to you. The first methods I described may be a good start.

Besides that, your isse is at the transitionend event binding:

```
    this.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function () {
      $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
      $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
      that.sliding = false
      setTimeout(function () { that.$element.trigger('slid') }, 0)
    })
```

For IE11 `$.support.transition.end` has the value `MSTransitionEnd` but this event does not work on it, the correct one should be only `transitionend`.

That bring us to start of the library at:

```
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')
      , transEndEventNames = {
           'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd'
        ,  'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend'
        ,  'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd'
        ,  'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd'
        ,  'transition'       : 'transitionend'
        }
      , name

    for (name in transEndEventNames){
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return transEndEventNames[name]
      }
    }
```

So we have to change the event name for msTransition to only transitionend:

```
transEndEventNames = {
          'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd'
        ,  'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend'
        ,  'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd'
        ,  'msTransition'     : 'transitionend'
        ,  'transition'       : 'transitionend'
        }
```

That will make your code work in IE11 (if you intend to use it other IE browsers I suggest you to test their compatibility).

Comment: It's a plus 1 but I can't test this now until the weekend. I will test it, and I will come back (I've even set a reminder on my phone!). Please don't see my lack of response as being rude :)

Comment: Finally got round to this, the change doesn't help, BUT, that's probably not the point; the post still answers the question of HOW to debug so although having everything done would be lovely, it's still the right answer!